# recommend a tutorial to read Excel file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have experience in C# but limited experience in using C# to read content from Excel. My task is very simple, just read each column of each row of an Excel document and retrieve their values.

Any good tutorials or samples for a beginner? I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5.

I am working with Excel 2007.

Comment: First of all specify your Excel version. In Office 2007 file formats completely changed and so there are different facilities of working with files for Office 97-2003 and Office 2007.

Comment: I need to work with Excel 2007. Thanks. Any good samples for me to learn how to read?

Answer (score 2):

Format of Excel 2007 files isn't straigtforward. Getting a text value of a cell using  [Open XML Format SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&DisplayLang=en) requires a lot of actions. If you're not going to use third party libraries, which don't know about, you have to get deeply into this SDK. There are tutorials, but I dont't know easy solution even for your simple task.

Comment: Are there any easy to use wrapper or libraries to manipulate Excel?

Comment: What the others in this topic suggest must be easier, but I suspect their solutions require Excel installed on the machine running the program and also not sure if they will work with Excel 2007. I you don't find easy solution, I can make copy and paste of my C# program code working with Excel 2007 files.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084).

Based on your description it is enough, but if you need to create an Add-in I would just look at VSTO.
just google/bing it, rather easy :)

Comment: Looks like no read sample, all of them are how to write? :-)

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will do it. Here is a simple example in a C# console application:

```
using System;
using SpreadsheetGear;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Load Book.xlsx.
            IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook(@"c:\Book.xlsx");
            // Write the address and formatted text value of each
            // cell to the console.
            foreach (IRange cell in workbook.Worksheets[0].UsedRange)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}='{1}'", cell.Address, cell.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

You can download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) and try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC